# Kotlin list.map with if changing returning value

Tags: android, kotlin

I am on a android app and I am triying to modify this code in order to only add to the List of DataItem if a condition is met (DataItem.PlanificacionItem(it).planificacion.diaP == 0). If I put an `if` inside the map, it changes from `List<DataItem>` to `List<Any>` and if I put an `else {null}` then i get the following error: `kotlin.NoWhenBranchMatchedException`

```
fun addHeaderAndSubmitList(list: List<PlaniFicacion>?) {
        adapterScope.launch {
            val items = when (list) {
                null -> listOf(DataItem.Header)
                else -> listOf(DataItem.Header) + list.map {if (DataItem.PlanificacionItem(it).planificacion.diaP == 0) {
                    DataItem.PlanificacionItem(it) } else {null}} + listOf(DataItem.Header_2)}




            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                submitList(items)
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should prefer `when` over inline if-else for good style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use list.filterNot(it -> it.planificacion.diaP == 0) and not list.map: